# Add new value to new column based on if value exists in other dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes called *users* and *purchases* with thousands of datasets to each. Both have a feature called *ID*.

My aim is to add a new column called *buyer* to the dataframe *purchases*, if the value of *ID* of *purchases* exists in *ID* of *users*.

So the two dataframes look like this:

```
users = data.frame("ID" = c(23432,75645,5465645,5656,6456))
purchases = data.frame("ID" = c(6456,4436,88945))
```

It should look like:
[image: Desired outcome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to compare the values and wrap `as.integer` to convert logical values to integers.

```
purchases$buyers <- as.integer(purchases$ID %in% users$ID)
purchases

#     ID buyers
#1  6456      1
#2  4436      0
#3 88945      0
```

This can also be written as :

```
purchases$buyers <- +(purchases$ID %in% users$ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ifelse`

```
purchases$buyersr <- ifelse(purchases$ID %in% users$ID, 1, 0)
```